# $.ajax() and "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I tried out several ways to get .json file and data using $.getJSON and $.ajax() [overthere](http://d.codio.com/hugolpz/getJson--/App/index.html)

**My JS code** n⁰2 fails :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'js/main.js',
  data: data,
  success: 1,
  }).done(function ( data ) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data.tata.entities.q142.labels.fr.value, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">Test 2:' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

**In Chrome console, the message error is** :

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"
```

**Refering to** the line :

```
  data: data,
```

**What is going wrong ? What to do ?**

---

**Edit:** all is done client side.

Comment: Do you have a variable somewhere where the data you want to send to the server is stored? It's trying to `GET` with some data attached in the form of a querystring `?something=blah`

Comment: Do you have any variable with name as `data` ? if so please post that variable's data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is being caused because you didn't define the variable data, so try removing the `data: data` line, it looks like you're just getting a JavaScript file which wouldn't normally take a query string:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'js/main.js',
  success: success,
  }).done(function ( data ) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data.tata.entities.q142.labels.fr.value, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">Test 2:' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: Did it work for you ? It didn't for me. I'am digging around your idea, maybe some conflicts with my Code 1, Code 3, Code 4.

Comment: Ok, my former code hidden a second bug. Line`success: success,` to change into `success : 1,` in accordance with my json data. Then your answer works :)