# Cannot reach my controller via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax for the first time.

The issue I am getting an error: [uncaught referenceError: Data is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743483/ajax-and-uncaught-referenceerror-data-is-not-defined) which I can see in Firebug

```
 <script>
        $(function () {

            var form = $("#ringMeBack");

            form.submit(function () {

                var emailData = {
                    RingMeBackName: $("#ringMeBackName").val(),
                    RingMeBackNumber: $("#ringMeBackNumber").val()
                    //, RingMeBackTime: $("#ringMeBackTime").val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/RingMeBack",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: JSON.stringify(emailData),   //THIS IS THE ERROR
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("There was an error... please try again.");
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
</script>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("RingMeBack", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ringMeBack" }))
        {
            <p>
                <input type="text" id="ringMeBackName" title="Optional, but it's nice to know who we are talking to." placeholder="Your name" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" id="ringMeBackNumber" title="We need to know the best number to call you on." placeholder="Your phone number" />
            </p>
            <p>
                When is a good time to call you?
            </p>
            <p>
                <select title="When is the best time to call you?" id="ringMeBackTime">
                    <!--don't show if it's after 2pm -->
                    @if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 14)
                    {
                        <option value="asap">Today, as soon as possible</option>
                    }
                    <option value="am" id="ringBackMorning" /><!--values created in Javascript-->
                    <option value="pm" id="ringBackAfternoon" /><!--values created in Javascript-->
                </select>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Request call back" title="Send and we'll call you back" class="redButton"/>
            </p>

            @ViewBag.Status
        }
```

If I update the `data: JSON.stringify(emailData)` to `data: emailData.serialize()`, it makes no difference.

As per the link I cite, if I remove the line totally (`data: emailData.serialize()`), then it hits my controller but doesn't pass any values...

I have no idea how to resolve this.

If it helps, my controller is simply

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void RingMeBack(string RingMeBackName, string RingMeBackNumber)
    {
        //break point set just to see if hits this
        string s = "";
    }
```

Comment: `emailData.serialize` should definitely not work.

Comment: just pass the `emailData` without any serializing, since jQuery does the conversion internally for you.

Comment: `data: emailData,` calls the `error: function()` .

Comment: What happens if you remove the contentType parameter?

Comment: ins't it `form.serialize()`? the `serialize` function is made to be used on a "form" element, and not on a random object http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Yeah, using .serialize is definitely the wrong avenue.

Comment: not only that, but as you set the content-type, what happens if you just send the object to the `data` parameter, instead of the json string version of it?

Comment: OP addressed that in the third comment: "`data: emailData`, calls the `error: function()`". Which as far as I can tell, means that setting the data to `data: emailData` does fix the problem at hand, and the issue is just the controller not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, jQuery should do the conversion from the object to JSON for you,  so you can just set the data parameter to `data: emailData`. The reason you're then hitting the error function is because the controller isn't returning anything -- you're not seeing a successful ajax transaction.

Comment: I tried, same error persists... I updated my Controller to return a ContentResult.

Comment: Well then there must be something else wrong with your request -- I don't know, I'll keep thinking. But that's the correct syntax for passing the data.

Comment: I thought you'd like to know, I fixed the issue. Returning type void was not the problem as I've tested it with void - it does not throw an exception...

Answer (score 0):

The answer was due to a silly mistake

```
RingMeBackName: $("#ringMeBackName").val(),
RingMeBackNumber: $("#ringMeBackNumber").val()
```

Should have been

```
'RingMeBackName': $("#ringMeBackName").val(),
'RingMeBackNumber': $("#ringMeBackNumber").val()
```

Note the single quote marks.

`JSON.stringify(theObject)` IS required